# Constructors and inheritance c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

this a constructor of class TXTArgon, which is a subclass of Particule. "m_" is an attribute of the class Particule. I need to specify the m_ of TXTArgon par default with value 18.0. 
I get an error : " class 'TXTArgon' doesn't have any field named 'm_' ". But m_ is in protected...

```
TXTArgon::TXTArgon () 
: Particule(),
  m_(18.0),
  nom_("TXTAr")
{
}
```

Does anybody see how can I correct this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only initialize `m_` via a constructor of `Particule`. If `Particule` doesn't have a suitable constructor, then what you can do is change its value *after* it has been initialized:

```
TXTArgon::TXTArgon () 
: Particule(),
  nom_("TXTAr")
{
  m_ = 18.0; // or m_ = TheTypeOfM_(18.0)
}
```

Comment: Or pass it to Particle constructor as an argument.